# Rails changing a proc to a method to validate if present in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model that has a long list of attributes. Not all attributes need to be present to save, but, if they are present I want to validate them.

Currently I am adding an `if:` proc to the end of each validation as such:

```
# app/models/bio.rb
class Bio < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }, if: Proc.new { |a| a.age.present? }
  validates :height, numericality: { only_integer: true }, if: Proc.new { |a| a.height.present? }
  validates :weight, numericality: { only_integer: true }, if: Proc.new { |a| a.weight.present? }
  ...
end
```

This doesn't seem very DRY, so, I wanted to move this proc to a class method and call it via it's symbol as:

```
...
validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }, if: :has_attr(:age)
...
def has_attr(a)
  #some_code.a.present?
end
```

I'm just unsure what the `a` in the proc refers to. I am assuming it's `self` or something similar.

How do I need to modify the method to get it to work the same as the proc? And do I need to add a `?` to the method name, such as `def has_attr?(a)` or `def has_attr(a)?`? And, honestly, I'm not even sure if you can pass an argument to a symbol. Any light you can shed on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way, the `:if` option wants something callable (such as a `Proc` or lambda) or a symbol which names an instance method. There's no way to tunnel arguments down to the instance method unless you want to wrap it as in your first example.

However, in this case, you can say [`allow_nil: true`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil) which will have the same effect:

```
validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_nil: true
# ----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Adding that will skip the validation if the `age` is `nil` and that should have the same effect as your current logic.

---

You could do something close to what you were trying to do with a class method that returns lambdas. Something like:

```
def self.has_attr(a)
  ->(obj) { obj.public_send(a).present? }
end
```

and then:

```
validates :age, ..., if: has_attr(:age)
```

You'd need to arrange for `self.has_attr` to be defined before your `validates` calls but that's not too hard, you'd probably put `has_attr` in a concern and include it at the top of your model class to deal with that problem and make `has_attr` easily available in other models as well.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly the kind of solution I really wanted.

Comment: @Josh BTW, I came up with something close to what you were originally trying to do using the classic "take the dog for a walk" technique. `allow_nil: true` is still what you want but the alternative might be useful in the future.

Comment: So far, the `allow_blank` validation seems to be working for what I needed. My forms all have 'default' answers such as blank stings and the validation seems to be skipping over those if no alternate answer is given. 
To clarify the purpose, the form builds a bio for the user and not all fields are required, but, if something is provided, I want to make sure it makes sense. I don't want people putting `age = 'immortal'` and such.